# Height did not update when switch from portrait to Landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, landscape-portrait

I create a `UIScrollView`, added other data in it, added subview to `self.view`. The problem is that when i switch my phone from portrait to *landscape* or vice versa it do not update the height so my `scrollview` do not work as i need to. here is the code:

```
UIScrollView *menuScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44+28+8, 130, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** method on your ViewController and change the frame of the **scrollView**.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];

    self.menuScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0,yPosition,width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hey one more thing i also want different frames on both portrait and landscape so i used  UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation but still it's not working when i switch from portrait to landscape

Comment: if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        
        menuScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44+28+8, 130, self.view.frame.size.height - 44+28+8)];}
    
    else{
        menuScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44+8, 130, self.view.frame.size.height - 44+8)];}

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view doesn't change its size because you haven't set any constraints at all.

There are two ways to do that. The first and really easy one, is to create both the scroll view and its subviews in Interface Builder, and set all the necessary constraints there. The second, harder way, is to programmatically set them, but if you're uncomfortable in doing that, then you should stick to the first option and do in your storyboard (or in a nib file) all the work.

Personally, I'd go with the first way, and I would create IBOutlet properties so I programmatically set any other properties of the subviews later in code.